# Seems to be a bug in MacOS FF's background-size:cover. How to avoid?

Tags: macos, firefox, css

Example: http://dabblet.com/gist/4161200

There is an empty 1px line on the bottom of the box. Probably it appears when we FF tries to fit image with odd number of lines. Anybody face this problem? How do you avoid it?

**Added:** Oh, sorry, I've checked it again and found out that this problem relates only to MacOS's Firefox (10.7 and 17.0 respectivily). On Windows it looks good.

Comment: I'm not seeing it on Firefox 17 on Windows.

Comment: Also can't see what you are talking about in Fx 17 on Ubuntu Linux.

Answer (score 1):

I also got the problem on FF17 on MacOSX. I can't explain why, but by turning off `background-repeat: no-repeat` this black extra pixel disappeared.